Proper use of voices in more complicated melodies
I have this section of a song that I'm trying to arrange onto a piano sheet.
Due to the way that the melody is written, there's a part where some notes are held at different intervals, and the phrasing is a bit complex in terms of intention.
I have decided to notate it this way and use multiple voices. My primary concern is if this design follows the more standard way of notating things, there are "mistakes"/bad practices in here or the sheet is too cluttered to read.


I'd be inclined to write the bass clef one octave higher, and use the legend 8vb rather than use all those leger lines. The objective of written dots is to make things as easy to read as possible.

@Tim Personally I would prefer the bass clef notes to be written exactly as they are written. You can actually see how many leger lines there are right away at a glance without really counting. No reason for an 8vb sign..

@LarsPeterSchultz - that's just a personal choice, each to his own.

@Tim You can say that of course.

It's not too cluttered.  The bass clef notes are fine, largely because they're octave jumps.  We're used to recognizing them.  I'm a little less happy about going down to treble clef E in bar 3, but don't see a viable alternative.
I suspect this is what you want to hear, but if you've got an argument for using staccato crotchets instead. I'm listening.


The notation is fine and will be understood by any experienced enough pianist.
The left hand, though correct, is visually odd to me. Maybe increase the spacing between beats, so that the eighth notes and following quarter notes are further apart. Or perhaps rewrite the quarter notes as eighth notes and rests (understanding that might be interpretively problematic).

As long as notes played in both hands simultaneously are vertically aligned, it's o.k. I think.
